# How to get row matrix as an output from a mapped piecewise function?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, map, matlab

I have a piecewise function and want to understand what it is saying. Actually, I have to make a row vector matrix from it. The function is

[image: this is image link of piecewise function]

I just want to understand what is saying what will be the row vector matrix out of it  here is example of row vector

```
 A= [3 3 3; 2 3 2; 2 4 2];
```

The above is row vector matrices in MATLAB of 3x3

Comment: Look up [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html?q=Piecewise) in the docs.

Comment: yes i looked but i have row vector x `x=-15: 0.1 :15;` i want  to compute this to get y how

Comment: trying that but saying error `f = piecewise(-10<x<0, -4, (x.^2)-2, 30)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because nothing (inluding the comments) imply it's about Mathematica; it's rather about Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{Abs[x - 5], -10 < x < 0}, {-4, x == 0}, {x^2 - 2, 0 < x < 10}, 
        {30, True}}]

X = Range[-15, 15, 1]
```

> {-15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 
>   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}

```
{f /@ X};
% // MatrixForm
```

[image]